# Crawl data from online database on a Website

Tags: web-crawler, search-engine

I want to pull out data from an online database:
http://www.allmusic.com/advanced-search

On left hand side, there is a section "release data", where I can specify the start and end date of musics. No matter what dates I select, the URL "http://www.allmusic.com/advanced-search" doesn't get changed at all.

I want to write a little crawler, which starts at the URL "http://www.allmusic.com/advanced-search" and get all data out after I select a filtering date, i.e. "2010-2014". How can I associate the date section with the default URL so that the program can start from the first page and follow all links to get all data in that data range?

The URL http://www.allmusic.com/advanced-search alone doesn't work since it doesn't provide a starting page for me to crawl.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this feasible at all? Thanks.